# Unable to transfer files on android 8.0 TV box to the USB

Tags: usb, android-tv

Unable to transfer files on android 8.0 TV box to the USB.
I have tried many file transfer apps but none will transfer to my USB even though it shows my USB connection and any files that are on the USB. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [TotalCommander](https://apkpure.com/total-commander-file-manager/com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander)?  Its possible that the USB drive is mounted as read-only.  In TotalCommander, If you copy to the USB drive and the USB drive is mounted as read-only: TotalCommander will automatically ask if you want to remount the drive as read-write, which is what you want.  Say 'Yes', then it copies whatever files you want to your USB.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, total commander worked, it transferred the file without asking to remount the drive as read-write. No other programming would let me transfer files. Thanks again Jeff Luyet.